# Input email field onchange not setting string to state if last field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is really weird, I am setting an email input as a string to state and I can see on react dev tools that it gets sent, but If I try to log it from another function I get empty string, the thing is that If I change the order of the inputs and the email is not the last one then it all works.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useContext } from 'react'
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone'
import context from '../provider/context'
import axios from 'axios'

const File = () => {

  const { setStage, setProject, project, setUrls, urls, email, setEmail } = useContext(context)

  const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles) => uploadFile(acceptedFiles), [project])

  const { getRootProps, isDragActive, getInputProps } = useDropzone({ onDrop })


  // Set project name
  const addProject = (e) => setProject(e.target.value)

  // Set email address
  const addEmail = (e) => setEmail(e.target.value)

  // I got another function then that logs the `email` state, 
  // but if I do it right after typing on the email input I get empty  string.
  // If I invert the order, and `project` comes after the email input 
  // then it displays the email string just fine.


 return (
    <>
      <ul className='list'>
        <li>
          <label className='label' htmlFor='upload'>
            Project's Name
          </label>
          <input
            id='upload'
            value={project}
            type='text'
            name='project'
            placeholder='e.g Great Project'
            onChange={addProject}
            autoFocus
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <label className='label' htmlFor='email'>
            Your email address
          </label>
          <input
            id='email'
            type='email'
            name='email'
            value={email}
            placeholder='Email address to send notification to'
            onChange={addEmail}
          />
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div className='fileTitle' {...getRootProps()}>
          {isDragActive ? <p className='label'>Drop the file here ...</p> : handleResponse()}
          <div className='file'>
            <div id='drop-area' className={`drop-area ${isDragActive ? 'active' : ''}`}>
              <div className={`icon ${response ? response : ''}`}></div>
            </div>
            <input
              {...getInputProps()}
              className='inputfile'
              id='file'
              type='file'
              name='locations'
            />
          </div>
          <br />
          <em className='info'>
            * Don’t include any headers in the file, just your list of urls with{' '}
            <strong>no headers</strong>.
          </em>
        </div>
   </>
)}

export default File
```

The function that logs the email uses the react-dropzone plugin

```
 // Upload file
  const uploadFile = async (file) => {
    console.log(email)
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('urls', file[0])

    try {
      const options = {
        headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' },
        params: { project, email }
      }

      const res = await axios.post('/api/upload/', formData, options)

      setUrls(res.data.number)
      setResponse('success')

      setTimeout(() => setStage('process'), 1200)
    } catch (err) {
      setResponse(err.response.data)
    }
  }
```

Doing a simple onclick works fine

```
const checkEmail = () => {
 console.log(email) // This works cause it takes it form the useContext
}
```

And then on the html

```
<button onClick={checkEmail}>Click here<button>
```

Comment: `"I got another function"` How are we supposed to debug without seeing that function?

Comment: It's a bit complex it uses the useDropzone, ok I am updating the question

Comment: Try changing that function to a different function that just directly console logs to see if the function is the issue. It sounds like the problem is with that function

Comment: @Nate yes, it is the useDropzone a simple onclick button made it log just fine

Comment: Then please show use the code for the function. The problem is clearly within that function, and nobody can solve it without seeing that function.

Comment: @NateLevin, makes sense, at the time of writing the question I did not think it was to do with the react-dropzone

Comment: `email` is not a parameter of `uploadFile`. That is why reversing it works just fine.

Comment: @NateLevin, is not a parameter on Upload file, but it is a state, using context provider, I made earlier a simple function that did not have email as a parameter and it worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221114/discussion-between-nate-levin-and-alvaro).

Comment: Ok thanks, heading over to the chat

Answer (score 0):

In the end I needed to add `email` as an array dependency to the react-drop zone useCallback so it can register that something has change on that state.

so I changed:

```
const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles) => 
  uploadFile(acceptedFiles), [project])
```

To

```
const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles) => 
  uploadFile(acceptedFiles), [project, email])
```

And that is the reason why, when I changed the project field after adding the email it was working.

Many thanks to [@NateLevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13608595/nate-levin) who helped me find where the problem was at.